# Как залить сайт Django на хостинг?

Tags: django, сервер, hosting

У меня есть сайт на Django который уже готов и нужно залить на хостинг. Для этого Я использую программу FileZilla. Проблема в том что хостинг возвращает мне ошибку о том что файл index.html не был найден. То есть ищет index.html. А проблема в том что я использую Django и этот файл у меня лежит в папке templates.

Comment: Обращайтесь к документации вашего хостинга

Comment: чел кросава, деньги просто так потратил. Для Django не хостинг, а vds нужен.

Comment: @Lofectr некоторые хостинги имеют поддержку Django (но это естественно надо документацию читать)

Comment: А только VDS можно?

Comment: думаю более точный ответ ты сможешь получить у саппорта своего хостинга. Задай им вопрос в личном кабинете, что у тебя есть сайт на джанго и попроси инструкций, как его запустить. Если это можно сделать на твоем тарифе, тебе ответят как это можно сделать, если нет, то предложат выбрать альтернативный тариф

Answer (score 1):

Для Django лучше всего смотреть в сторону VPS (VDS). Есть хостинги с поддержкой django но из-за личных предпочтений (мелких глюков) мне не сильно интересны.

Поднять свой сервер и настроить его на самом деле не сложно.
Делал на связке Django + gunicorn + nginx + Supervisor(по желанию)

## Основы для запуска (по инету можно найти и более подробные руководства)

### Django + gunicorn + nginx

### Установка

```bsh
apt install python3
apt install python3-pip
apt install nginx
apt install nano
pip3 install django
pip3 install gunicorn
```

#### Создаем наш проект

```bsh
django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

или загружаем имеющийся
не забываем про collectstatic перед выкладкой, чтобы nginx мог ее корректно подгружать.

```bsh
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

Проект лучше создавать в виртуальном окружении.

#### Проверяем gunicorn

Из папки проекта там где лежит manage.py запускаем gunicorn указав Ваш IP

```bsh
gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application --bind 111.111.111.111:8000
```

При этом сайт будет отображаться без статических файлов это нормально!

Иногда gunicorn может оставаться в памяти

```bsh
killall gunicorn
```

### Настроим nginx

Перейдем в /etc/nginx/sites-available/

```bsh
cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/
```

и откроем default

```bsh
nano default
```

Удаляем оттуда все и пишем

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 111.111.111.111; # ip или доменное имя
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/site.log;

    location /static/ {
        root /opt/my_site/myproject/;  # где manage.py
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  }
```

Сохраняем, выходим, перезапускам nginx

```bsh
service nginx restart
```

Если все правильно переходим в браузере по адресу сайта и радуемся итогу.

### Supervisor (не обязательно но полезно...)

#### Есть мысль стоит перейти на systemd

Чтобы наше приложение стартовало после сбоя.

```bsh
apt install supervisor
```

Создадим конфиг файл для gunicorn

```bsh
cd /opt/my_site/myproject/myproject` # каталог с settings.py

touch gunicorn.conf.py
```

Открываем

```bsh
nano gunicorn.conf.py
```

Пишем

```
bind = '127.0.0.1:8000'
workers = 3
user = "nobody"
```

создадим конфиг супервизора и отредактируем его

```bsh
cd /etc/supervisor/conf.d/

touch myproject.conf

nano myproject.conf
```

Пишем наш конфиг

```
[program:myproject]
command=/opt/my_site/env/bin/gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application -c /opt/my_site/myproject/myproject/gunicorn.conf.py
directory=/opt/my_site/myproject
user=nobody
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

#### Команды для supervisor

```bsh
supervisorctl reread
supervisorctl update
supervisorctl status myproject
supervisorctl restart myproject
```

Comment: supervisor потерял смысл после появления systemd во всех основных дистрибутивах

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо за уточнение надо будет посмотреть что там нового наворотили ). Немного дополнил ответ.